# Read metadata of resource through Azure policy

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, azure-policy, azure-bicep

I want to read metadata of the resource which is deployed in Azure like eg: template.json and create Azure policy definition to traverse through this metadata for every resource being deployed to perform pre-flight checks on all deployments

```
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "metadata": {
        "_generator": {
            "name": "bicep",
            "version": "0.4.63.48766",
            "templateHash": "16811656036359979319"
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "tagNames": {
            "type": "array"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, you mean you'd like to ouput all the tags on any resource ? What kind of check are you planning ?

Comment: I want to check if the deployment has happened using specific template spec json template which has metadata written "_generator"  - "bicep"